# getting A set into a sorted array perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, set, scalar

I have been looking for a way to convert a set into a sorted array.

I have found a solution but it seems a little bit rediculous:

```
use Set::Scalar;
Set::Scalar->as_string_callback(sub{join("\n", sort $_[0]->elements)});
#above formats print so that a line is added between each element
... #assume things are added to the set in this code
my @arr = split("\n", "$set"); #array contains each sorted element of the set
```

my only issue is that in my eyes this shouldn't be a fast/memory efficient method of doing this. Please let me know if you have any advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @arr = sort $set->elements;
```